# Social websites are not showing updated meta tags on share?

Tags: angular, metadata, facebook-sharer

I am using meta service for meta tags update. I am able to update the default tags with meta service in index.html , and I am able to see the updated tags in inspect element console. social sites are showing default meta tags only.
but these updated tags are not showing up in the social websites sharing.

**index.html with default static meta tags**

```
    <meta property="og:url " content="https://example.com/AngularApp/#/embed-video/PRIVATE/3867c8e2-85ba-4ca9-9804-b28769e67746">
<meta property="og:description" content="Grace is the only complete studio album by Jeff Buckley, released on August 23, 1994..">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/vod/images/125/03022017/flight1486153663429_play1.gif">
```

**Component for updated tags:**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.metaService.updateTag({ content: 'https://example.com/vod/images/125/03022017/test.gif'}, "property='og:image'");
    this.metaService.updateTag({content:'Updated Text'}, "property ='og:description'");
}
```

After loading this component, these two tags **('og:description' and 'og:image')** are updating with with new content. but in the social share fb and other websites are taking default meta tags from index.html when i share the url. these old tags are updated with new tags I am seeing in the inspect element console. I am not seeing the new meta content in the scocial websites.
followed this Meta Code
How can i show the updated meta tags in the social websites?

**Angular version: 4.0.X**

facebook is taking default tags not updated tags. how to fix the problem?

Comment: When you share content on social media, their crawler will fetch the shared URL to extract content through OG protocol. Such crawler usually cant parse Javascript, so they only see your index.html page. You have to enable server-side rendering of your application if you want them to see your fully rendered content ( including dynamics meta ). see https://universal.angular.io/ for more info on server side rendering

Comment: i have using Angular 4 but u you can specify for Angular 2 can you explain elaborate @PierreMallet

Comment: I do not understand your comment (sorry)